# Need a synonym for "action" in a specific context

Tags: synonyms

I need a synonym for the word "action". Here is the sentence where I need a synonym:

When an **event** occurs, an **action** is taken.

For example:

When you **read this question**, you **write a comment**.

Comment: synonyms: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/action?s=t

Comment: In your specific use case, "action" is probably the best option.

Answer (score 1):

When an event occurs, **a reaction follows**.

You could also say: "an event here will certainly **trigger a reaction**."

> - reaction - (noun) -  "the way someone acts or feels in response to something that happens, is said, etc." [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reaction?show=0&t=1422308512) "a response to a stimulus" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reaction)

Another choice would be: "a response"

Answer (score 0):

"**Trigger**" (verb meaning to cause) is a word we commonly use in software engineering.

```
The occurrence of event X triggers action Y
```

or

```
The occurrence of event X triggers event Y
```

"reaction" is another synonym, although it has a more general purpose and does not necessarily imply a procedural standard action taking place. It is also widely used to refer to natural reaction or instinct.

Answer (score 0):

A *[response](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/response)* is a general term

> A reaction to something:
>
> *an extended, jazzy piano solo drew the biggest response from the crowd*
>
> *an honors degree course in Japanese has been established in response to an increasing demand*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*